Instance of Mathematica uses CPU constantly at high level
I was doing some long lasting computations and this is my CPU usage:

There is kernel using approximately quarter of capacity of CPU. This is OK because of the calculation performed.
But then there is also "Untitled-1" instance of Mathematica consuming another quarter of capacity.
Then I stopped the calculation and kernel usage went to zero but "Untitled-1" constantly consumes quarter of capacity.

I have no dynamics in the notebook just few static plots and a code for doing numerical computation. What can be the cause?
Normally this does not happen to me but I had this notebook opened on my PC for several days.
I guess there is no way to restart notebook and keeping the kernel untouched?

What kind of calculations were they, roughly speaking? Linear algebra, parallelization ...? Do you perhaps have a simple way to replicate this? Also, in your second screenshot, it still says (Running...), there still might be some data transfer between the kernel and the front-end ...

Good point, it shows running there but "Running" from window title of the notebook disappeared when I stopped computation. It shows running only in Windows task manager. The calculation was simple arithmetic, really just +, -, *, /, Log. It was just a lot of these and for a long time.
